History's state strategy of stack overflow
How it works:

Have some notifications (the notification badge numbers)
Navigate to somewhere else
Go back and still see the notification badge numbers

My expectation: to understand the strategy of StackOverflow (store history state) or something similar
Here is the described video: https://imgur.com/dbjMaic
And this is the state I found in session storage (if it is not relevant please comment below I will remove it)

